# Output into new column .CSV Shell

Tags: macos, shell, csv, newline

I am still new to Shell. In javascript it is super easy to parse all output into a new column. Allyou need is `,`. But I am still struggling to do the same in Shell. I've traversed most of the anwsers on Stackoverflow, and still couldn't get it to work. Most of the anwsers are around cutting from an existing file and pasting into a new one etc. Pretty sure, somewhere I am making a simple syntax error.

At the moment I have this:

```
echo "Mq1:" >> ~/Desktop/howmanySKUs.csv

cd /Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/Mannequin_1_WIP && ls |grep \_01.tif$ | wc -l | sed "s/,//" >> ~/Desktop/howmanySKUs.csv
```

It counts the amount of files in specified directory.

**I get this:**

[image]

But now I am trying to Output `Mq1:` in one column, and then the sum of found files in the 2nd column.

**Desired Output:**

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It didn't output into a new column, but now it is all under one line. Which works for my purpose. Thanks! If you post it as an Anwser I will accept it  :P

Comment: Can't really post `man echo` as an answer. :D Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly append both the lines

```
cd /Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/Mannequin_1_WIP && echo "Mq1:,"`ls |grep \_01.tif$ | wc -l` > ~/Desktop/howmanySKUs.csv
```